# How to Resolve Tainted Canvas for Frame Grab of Remote Video on Cordova Android App?

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

So I have an application we are developing in Cordova for Android.  Specifically, the user will load a video feed that the application will do real-time processing.  At issue is, a CORS violation which results in a Tainted Canvas when attempting to execute `toDataURL` on a canvas element.  Maybe we are going about this wrong, but in short, we load the video to a `video` tag and then use `canvas` to snag frames every 100 milliseconds then submit the base64 data to be processed and this is where the error comes in.

Here is the loading code:

```
videoElement.src = loadedFeed; //http://someserver.com/hls/somefeed.m3u8
videoElement.crossOrigin = "*"; //have also tried anonymous
videoElement.play()
```

Here is the image creation code:

```
var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
canvas.height = videoElement.videoHeight;
canvas.width = videoElement.videoWidth;
canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(videoElement, 0, 0,canvas.width, canvas.height);
var base64data = canvas.toDataURL();
```

As we do not control the remote server, we cannot dictate the CORS headers.  The video loads fine in the `video` tag and plays without issue, but we can't get a single frame into base64 data as the following is the error:

```
Uncaught SecurityError: Failed to execute toDataURL on HTMLCanvasElement: Tainted canvases may not be exported
```

Any thoughts on what we are doing wrong or what we can try different?  In addition to crossOrigin, we have tried the Cordova Whitelist plugin with:

```
<allow-navigation href="*"/>
<allow-intent href="*"/>
<access origin="*" />
```

I have looked at numerous SO answers and have yet to find the exact flavor of my issue, but do let me know if you find one.

Answer (score 3):

Try to use `<video id="video" crossorigin="anonymous"/>`

It fixed issue in my case.

Hope it helps.

Comment: We tried it and no go. Tried it in the tag and tried it via js.

Answer (score 2):

I have faced the same issue for loading an image.
here is what worked for me, hope helps you.

What I have done is,

1. downloaded the image using xhr request and saved it in fileReader.
2. Painted it on canvas then converted back to image dataURL.
   In this case, it was an SVG blob URL, you can use whatever you are receiving.

```
function downloadImageFromCrossOrigin (blobURL) {
                var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
                xhr.open('GET', blobURL, true);
                xhr.responseType = 'blob';
                xhr.onload = function () {
                    if (this.status === 200) {
                        var fileReader = new FileReader();
                        fileReader.onload = function (e) {
                            var url = e.target.result;
                            var img = new Image();
                            var imgCanvas = document.createElement('canvas');
                            var imgContext = imgCanvas.getContext('2d');
                            img.onload = function () {
                                // Make sure canvas is as big as the picture
                                imgCanvas.width = img.width;
                                imgCanvas.height = img.height;
                                // Draw image into canvas element
                                imgContext.drawImage(img, 0, 0);

                                // Get canvas contents as a data URL. Use this imgAsDataURL
                                var imgAsDataURL = imgCanvas.toDataURL('image/png');

                            };
                            img.src = url;
                        };
                        fileReader.readAsDataURL(this.response);
                    }
                    else{
                        throw new Error('Failed to load from blobURL.');
                    }
                };
                xhr.send();
            };
```

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` is also subject to [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Comment: And it's not an image but a video stream